# Expansion of $\phi (x)$ in the derivation of WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, approximations, semiclassical

In the derivation, we assume the eigenfunctions of $H$ to have the form $$\psi (x)=e^{i \phi(x)/\hbar}$$ where $\phi (x)$ is allowed to take any complex value.

But then suddenly we assume this expansion of $\phi (x)$ in terms of $\hbar$:

$$\phi (x)=\phi _0 (x)+ \phi _1 (x)\hbar + \phi _2 (x) \hbar^2+....$$

We assume the higher powers of $\hbar$ are negligible (in our approximation) and then feed this into the Schrodinger equation.

My question is about the expansion. What on earth is this expansion? It's not a Taylor series or anything (where we can neglect higher order terms). How is this expansion of $\phi (x)$ even unique? What determines $\phi _0 (x)$, $\phi_1 (x)$, etc in this expansion? Can't we make this expansion whatever we want?

Comment: Which derivation? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141356/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expansion is a Taylor expansion (actually an [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion)), of the phase of the wavefunction. And the point of the WKB *approximation* is that you will eventually truncate the series.

The way the different terms at each order in $h$ are fixed are following an iterative procedure. At order $h^n$, you plug the ansatz into the Schrodinger equation and keep all terms at the same order in $h$ (note that the momentum-squared operator $p^2/2m$ is intrinsically order $h^2$, since the Laplacian is multiplied by $\hbar^2$; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#Application_to_the_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)). This will give you a differential equation that lets you solve for $\phi_n$ in terms of lower order approximations to the phase, as well as any source terms (zeroth-order terms in $\phi$).

There's an explicit example of how this works on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#An_example).