# Classical limit of quantum mechanics from decoherence or diminishing hbar?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, path-integral, decoherence

Two pictures regarding the classical limit of quantum mechanics. One says in path integral take hbar to zero then the paths constructively interference near the classical path and the paths deviate far away cancel out. The other says decoherence of a quantum system with macroscopic environment, which has untrackably many degrees of freedom. I don't see how these two classical transitions reconcile each other. The former seems to suggest a particle whose action is much larger than hbar will behave classically, and the latter seems to argue from interactions with many other particles making the particle classical. How are they consistent?

Comment: Closely related and possibly a duplicate: [Is  ℏ→0
  in path integral merely technical thing? Is there any justification? (especially in open quantum theory)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622221/is-hbar-rightarrow-0-in-path-integral-merely-technical-thing-is-there-any)

Comment: Not sure if you'd like a [classic](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-35/issue-4/The-classical-limit-for-quantum-mechanical-correlation-functions/cmp/1103859623.full) by Hepp.

Comment: Might try [this](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/ad0533) as well...