# How to prove Newton's second law with quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Newton's second law claims that $F=ma$. In terms of quantum mechanics, the equality can be written as $ \frac{d\langle p \rangle}{dt} = -\langle \nabla V(x) \rangle$. How can I prove this with non-relativistic Schrodinger Equation?

I've calculated the expectation of $p=mv$, and tried to take the derivative under the integral. And there I'm stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17651/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks! I searched the site but somehow didn't find it. But actually I still have some difficulties with the deduction

Comment: It's OK, I found the way to do the maths here http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=248520, by searching "Ehrenfest Theorem"