# The emergence of classical physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am reading a book called *Sleeping Beauties in Theoretical Physics*. In chapter 2 of this book the writer is trying to describe the emergence of classical mechanics from quantum mechanics. I have seen the emergence of  classical mechanics from quantum mechanics before from Path Integral. Moreover, I have read [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108222/from-quantum-mechanics-to-classical-mechanics) also. However, I am having problem following this logic. I do not understand his approach (specially the taylor expansion in equation 2.2 and equation 2.8)
Addendum: I do know that he is trying to get to Hamilton-Jacobi Equation (2.9) (via Eikonal approximation)

[image: PAGE # 8]
[image: PAGE # 10]

Comment: I have used Taylor series expansion many times but I do not understand what he is doing in 2.2  and 2.8. The meaning of taylor series expansion there is not that clear to me(which I have already mentioned in thequestion above). I do know that he is trying to get to Hamilton-Jacobi Equation (via Eikonal approximation).

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your issue with (2.2) is? How is it any different from other Taylor series you've dealt with?

Answer (score 1):

1. Perhaps OP would be more satisfied if we first changed the variable $$\Psi~=~e^{\Phi}\tag{1}$$ in the [TDSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) so that it becomes a non-linear [Riccati equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)
   $$ i\hbar  \dot{\Phi}~=~-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (\Phi^{\prime\prime}+\Phi^{\prime2}) + V. \tag{2}$$
2. Now claim that $\Phi$ is a truncated formal [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of the form
   $$ \Phi~=~\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \Phi_n \hbar^n , \qquad N\in\ \mathbb{Z}.\tag{3}$$
   It is truncated at the term $n=N$ because we expert a correspondence with classical physics. Also note that formal multiplication of truncated Laurent series is well-defined and makes sense. Hence the Riccati eq. (2) becomes an [infinite tower of equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation).
3. Next adjust $N=-1$ and rename $\Phi_{-1}=iS_0$, so that the leading equation in eq. (2) is the [Hamilton-Jacobi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)/[Eikonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation) equation.
4. Finally rename $$\Phi~=~\frac{i}{\hbar} S + \ln R, \tag{4}$$
   where $S$ and $R$ are Taylor series in $\hbar$. The variable $\Phi$ may be viewed as an [asymptotic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) in $\hbar$.