What is currently the currently understood relationship between classical and quantum world?
Which of these is understood to be the relationship between classical and quantum mechanics? Or is it a mixture of these, or something else entirely?

The classical world comprises of measurement outcomes that emerge from quantum mechanics. The universe is fundamentally a quantum state, from which measurement outcomes emerge through a process which is not completely understood yet (some approaches can be decoherence or objective collapse theories). And the classical world is just the set of measurement outcomes.

The classical world corresponds to coherent  states of the quantum mechanical wavefunction. In this approach too, the classical world emerges from quantum mechanics, but the correspondence is at the wavefunction level and doesn't have to do with measurements.

The classical world is assumed to exist as part of the definition of Quantum Mechanics. This is because measurements require an interaction between a quantum system and a classical environment. This means both classical and quantum mechanics co-exist and are equally fundamental.


I want to know the modern understanding of this, where we stand currently in understanding the classical world.

The “classical world” is just the world on a scale where quantum effects don’t really matter. The world consists entirely of quantum mechanics and general relativity (or, in the future once we figure it out, unified field theory).

@controlgroup both 1. and 2. correspond to that. Which one is it? And what about the third one?

Both 1 and 2 correspond to the quantum world, and 3 is false (QM is separate from classical mechanics). The “classical world” is just a scale where both QM and GR have very very simple and accurate approximations.

Why are people down-voting this question?  It's asking about an unresolved specific issue of significant importance in quantum foundations.  Just because there's no consensus doesn't mean that it's a bad question to ask about our state of current understanding.

@KenWharton this question is very broad and almost opinion-based.  It is an important question but not necessarily a good fit for the site.  (FYI I am not the downvoter)

I don’t think 2. is true, at least not without a lot of context.  Coherent states may be semi-classical in a sense, but there converse statement needs a lot of explanations. Coherent states are defined (in the Perelomov sense) for groups and I don’t see how or why the “classical” world (on that apparently includes measurements) should have a group structure.

By deeply observing the ways of the classical world, we discovered that we need quantum mechanics. Some people think that this means that QM gives rise to the classical world, but there is no proof of that at the moment. So, both exists, and we do not know the relation between them - your question is an open question.

As to option 2, the classical world overwhelmingly corresponds to incoherent states. This is why a cat cannot be in a superposition state. Macroscopic coherent states do exist, however, in the form of ferromagnetic domains, superconductors, superfluids, lasers, etc. I guess even crystals could be seen as a form of macroscopic coherence.

Classical physics describes a system in terms of variables like $x(t)$ for the $x$ position of a particle. When you measure $x(t)$ you also get the value $x(t)$.
The equations of motion of quantum theory describe a system in terms of operators called observables that can be represented by Hermitian matrices. The possible results of measuring an observable are its eigenvalues. Quantum theory predicts a probability for each of the possible outcomes that depends on the situation in which the measurement is being conducted, specifically on the outcomes of past measurements as summarised in the quantum state, which records which observables were measured and the values obtained.
In general the outcome of a quantum experiment will depend on what happened to all of the eigenvalues of the measured observable during the experiment: this is called quantum interference. For an example, see Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
The description I've given so far is fairly uncontroversial but what is controversial is what is happening in reality to bring about the predictions of quantum theory. This controversy is related to the relationship between quantum and classical physics. The different accounts of what is happening in reality to bring about the predictions of quantum theory are called interpretations of quantum theory.
Some of the interpretations say there is no account of what is happening in reality such as the Copenhagen or statistical interpretations of quantum theory. Classical physics works in everyday life and you're not allowed to ask about what is happening in quantum experiments. In an experiment you try to test a theory by setting up a situation which results in particular predictions when described in terms of that theory. So if your theory provides no description of reality, as with these interpretations, it doesn't allow you to test whether an experiment is set up correctly if you take it seriously. I don't see why anyone would adopt such a theory but some people do.
There are other theories that modify the equations of motion of quantum theory such as spontaneous collapse theories, which say that all of the different versions of a system regularly get cut down to just one version:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
Or pilot wave theories, which say that the real world consists of a bunch of particles that interact with the observables according to their own equation of motion:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2411.10782
These theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic quantum theories that provide the bulk of experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Some physicists are doing research on improving and testing these theories.
Another way of thinking about quantum theory is to apply its equations of motion to reality in the way we would apply any other scientific theory. Interference and other quantum phenomena can be explained in terms of the existence of multiple versions of each system.
When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Objects in everyday life that are large enough for you to see at all have information copied out of them a lot faster than the timescales over which they change significantly. As a result decoherence suppresses interference very effectively for those objects. This tends to result in the versions of the objects you see around evolving independently of one another in layers each of which acts approximately like the universe as described by classical physics:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This is called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory. Some physicists don't like it. A selection of criticisms:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.05377
https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0810
https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0624

None of the above because there is no "classical world", there is only the quantum. But due to a number of effects (some which make for nice calculations, others which seem hopelessly intractable) there are wavefunctions which appear very sharply peaked over a macroscopic scale and would be infinitely sharply peaked if we took $\hbar \to 0$. This is enough to "trick" humans into developing classical mechanics first as a way of modelling these quantum phenomena.

The only interpretation of quantum theory which would agree with these statements is Everettian/Many-Worlds.  In every other viewpoint there are events which could be said to be part of a classical world (meaurement outcomes, Bohmian particles, dynamically-collapsed wavefunction-fields, etc. etc.)

What's real? Wavefunctions, measurements, both?

The Ehrenfest theorem does not lead to the classical world. See for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17651/109928 and the https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0150 paper cited in one of the answers there.

There is no quantum world. There is only an abstract quantum physical description. -- Niels Bohr.

"Mechanics" is an abstraction by definition. It used to be that QM was needed for some things and CM for others. But science has progressed passed this point and all data is now consistent with CM being an approximation to QM. I.e. the thing that every viewpoint except Many Worlds tries to modify.

A simple but provably limited approach is the direct correspondence between classical and quantum theory occuring in Dirac's procedure of canonical quantization which relates the Poisson bracket of Hamiltonian Mechanics to the commutators of quantum theory.
$$\{A,B\} \rightarrow \frac{1}{i\hbar} [\hat{A},\hat{B}]$$
One of the least appreciated aspects of current theory is that it is the merging of basic single particle quantum mechanics with special relativity which gave rise to quantum field theory via the need for the second quantization of the quantum theory (e.g. counting of particles obeying pauli exclusion principle and their respective energies)
Special relativity in some sense breaks the very stable world described by the Schrodinger equation by forcing time to mix with space.  In the non-relativistic world described by the Schrodinger equation there is no ambiguity that time and space are seperate.  The wave equation in the Schrodinger world is perfectly deterministic and evolves deterministically. It however doesn't describe a world full of the particles that we see every day.
It is only with the incorporation of special relativity that we see something resembling the world we know.
This relationship between spin and the classical world is still truly not fully understood and was already noted as being important to the quantization of gravity as early as 1939 by Fierz and Pauli as they probed the nature of spin-2 particles in weak gravitational fields.
It is an intriguing possibility that if we better understood how spin statistics actually arose we might close the gap between the quantum and the classical.
